# Transaction cost not correct on API -

Tags: transactions, gas, javascript, gas-price

I'm analyzing this [**transaction**](https://etherscan.io/tx/0xdbab1a5aad83f4a49296faba877f69d49684009252379c0874a3cb2b1b599af8)

If you open the [**api transaction details**](https://api.etherscan.io/api?module=proxy&action=eth_getTransactionByHash&txhash=0xdbab1a5aad83f4a49296faba877f69d49684009252379c0874a3cb2b1b599af8&apikey=18DRAAU1XM9M6P6E58QKN26TCAIBKENG8K)

You can see

1. gas "0x490b4"
2. gasPrice    "0x26e1f9c600"

By converting them to decimal and calculating we got total of : 0.049964396 Ether but if we compare with etherscan page there it says 0.036807301 Ether

What I'm i doing wrong

```
parseInt(0x490b4) * (parseInt(0x26e1f9c600) * 10 ** -18)
```

On picture everything is shown

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use gasUsed instead of gas to compute total paid

- gasUsed 220403
- gasPrice 167000000000

Then gasUsed * gasPrice / 10**18 = 0.036807301 ETH